# Connecting to Postgres Cloud SQL from App Engine Standard with IAM is timing out?

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Upon trying the sample code here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard#connect-connectors ... And here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins

... The connection times out when using the private IP (but correctly resolves the private IP using the instance name), and the same code with the public IP (by adjusting the dialer) says:

> failed SASL auth (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "<IAM SERVICE ACCOUNT AUTHORIZED FOR DB>" (SQLSTATE 28P01)

Connecting with IAM **does** work through the Cloud SQL Proxy on my client machine. Since neither of these options are working for App Engine Standard, and the logs show no helpful information, is there a known solution or suggestion on a workaround?

---

I'm using Go, "edited down" version of the code here...

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net"

    "cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn"
    pgx "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
    pgxStdlib "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib"
)

func test() {
    var dialOptions []cloudsqlconn.DialOption

    if usePrivateIP {
        dialOptions = append(dialOptions, cloudsqlconn.WithPrivateIP())
    }

    var dialer *cloudsqlconn.Dialer
    dialer, err := cloudsqlconn.NewDialer(
        context.Background(),
        cloudsqlconn.WithIAMAuthN(),
        cloudsqlconn.WithDefaultDialOptions(dialOptions...),
    )

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    config, err =: pgx.ParseConfig(fmt.Sprintf(
        "user=%s password=%s database=%s",
        user,
        password,
        databaseName,
    ))

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

     config.DialFunc = func(ctx context.Context, _ string, _ string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return dialer.Dial(ctx, instanceName)
    }

    var db *sql.DB
    db, err := sql.Open("pgx", pgxStdlib.RegisterConnConfig(config))

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    _ = db // should be live
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Go connection code and your app engine config?

Comment: It's the same as the example with a different instance name. I've double-checked everything there and I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `XX@appspot` rather than the full IAM Service Account (<strike>`XX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`</strike>) address.

Thanks to @enocom for highlighting this [in his comment when we were troubleshooting](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/issues/563#issuecomment-1594923679), as it's not clear the values aren't interchangeable from the documentation, and the Cloud SQL Proxy for client machines does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Private IP is probably timing out because you'll need to configure a Serverless VPC Access Connector to ensure a network path to your database.

When you tried public IP, you did connect to your database but authentication failed. This is probably because you're running your App Engine app as a separate IAM principal than your database user.

Here's how it looks all together:

```golang
    // password is intentionally blank
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=\"\" dbname=%s sslmode=disable", postgresUserIAM, postgresDB)
    config, err := pgx.ParseConfig(dsn)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to parse pgx config: %v", err)
    }
    d, err := cloudsqlconn.NewDialer(ctx, cloudsqlconn.WithIAMAuthN())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to initiate Dialer: %v", err)
    }
    defer d.Close()
    config.DialFunc = func(ctx context.Context, network string, instance string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return d.Dial(ctx, postgresConnName)
    }

    conn, connErr := pgx.ConnectConfig(ctx, config)
    if connErr != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to connect: %s", connErr)
    }
    defer conn.Close(ctx)

    var now time.Time
    err = conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), "SELECT NOW()").Scan(&now)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("QueryRow failed: %s", err)
    }
```

See how we wire it up [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/blob/main/e2e_postgres_test.go#L98-L133).

Comment: That's correct I have not set that up for this machine. It's an additional hourly cost to have the "Serverless VPC Access Connector" right? Is the advantage IAM ability and being able to keep things off of the public address space, or is there a way to do IAM still securely without external networking?

Comment: RE: "as a separate IAM principal than your database user" ... the service account has been granted access to the instance in the same way as my user account, which as mentioned does connect successfully from my client machine using Cloud SQL Proxy.

Comment: Just to be clear— the two primary goals here are: 1) the instance is not accessible publicly of course, 2) ideally credentials aren't necessary because the application itself as part of GCP is granted access

Comment: OK, so after a long conversation with ChatGPT trying to figure this out— I set up credentials (username/password for App Engine on Postgres) that are stored in the GCP Secret Manager and am connecting with the public IP. Not super thrilled about all of the extra steps and frustration here, it feels suboptimal from an implementation and logistics perspective. Still hoping to hear from you if possible about if there's a better way.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code for how you’re connecting? If I’m understanding correctly, you can do what you’re trying to.

Comment: Actually looking at the sample I wonder if you’re passing this option: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/cloudsqlconn#WithIAMAuthN

Comment: Yes I was, but I swapped it over to using username/password since then.

Comment: Added code, note that applying `cloudsqlconn.WithIAMAuthN()` also seems to work with the built-in authentication?

Comment: Added a separate example. This is getting hard to debug here. Feel free to open an issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector with all this information and we can get to the bottom of things.

Comment: I've tried a few different examples now and they all seem to give that "failed SASL auth (FATAL: password authentication failed...)" error if I try to use IAM. I'm starting to wonder if this is some kind of issue with how the instance is configured....

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/issues/563